# How to assume role with the new AWS GO SDK-V2 for cross account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk, assume-role

Following the GO SDK-v2 RC last Dec.24th, I have no idea how to create a config to assume a role in a different aws account. I couldn't find any doc or example and tried with the 'config.WithAssumeRoleCredentialsOptions' or with the 'stscreds.NewAssumeRoleProvider' without any result. Does anyone have an example or pointers for this?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the way to do it:

```
ctx := context.TODO()
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx,
    config.WithRegion("us-east-1"),
    //config.WithClientLogMode(aws.LogSigning),
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

stsClient := sts.NewFromConfig(cfg)
provider := stscreds.NewAssumeRoleProvider(stsClient, roleARN)
cfg.Credentials = aws.NewCredentialsCache(provider)

// without the following, I'm getting an error message: api error SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
creds, err := cfg.Credentials.Retrieve(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Some references for this:
* NewCredentialsCache - https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/#credentials--credential-providers
* AssumeRole - https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/#assumerole